# What is the way(best practice) to deal with XSS?

Tags: xss

I am using ASP.NET and on ASP.NET page has validate attribute which checks for the XSS validations. However i would like to know that is it really sufficient ?

I have visited some of the related post on stackoverflow and that helped me but i am looking to understand how to plan for XSS when developing web sites ?

Do we have to check XSS on client side, AJAX also ? How to do that ? Are there any tools which can help testing the XSS ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the basics:

- Do not allow HTML input
- Always html encode input when displaying it
- Use the [AntiXSSLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx) from Microsoft, or a similar library

Comment: Although people always say "do not modify user input when inserting it to the DB" which may contain HTML...

Comment: @Dor - Where did I say anything about inserting to DB?

Comment: You didn't, but when you receive input from the user, you usually insert that to the database.

Comment: Then how to deal with situation where we have to insert data into the database ? should we restrict the user while entering the data on client side ?

Comment: You insert into the DB what the client entered. When you display the data, html encode it (or use the AntiXSS Library).

Comment: @Anil Namde: Never trust the client-side limitations that you reflect on the user! Those limitations are for user convenience only!

Answer (score 2):

Check it out: [Allowing HTML and Preventing XSS](http://shiflett.org/blog/2007/mar/allowing-html-and-preventing-xss) @ shiflett.org