# <script type="text/javascript">alert('Xss done');</script>

Tags: xss

How do you resolve this Xss from Stackoverflow?

Comment: I didn't do anything... have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425328/what-is-the-waybest-practice-to-deal-with-xss

Comment: I didn't. Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky did.

Comment: im just trying to undertand how SO solve this problem but i recieve the answer sooner than i found the logic. I assume they use the escape() javascript function to avoid the Asp.net Exception for dangerous form text and then use UrlDecode with HtmlEncode to present the text in safe manner.
Thanks anyway you are faster than people use to say

Answer (score 3):

The output is html encoded.

All html entities are replaced with their escaped characters, for example "<" is replaced by `&lt;`.

More info on wikipedia along with a list of html characters, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML

Comment: http://www.htmlescape.net/htmlescape_tool.html here's a tool that illustrates exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff actually posted his Sanitizer on RefactorMyCode.com

You can see it [here](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html). It may not be the final version they're currently using, but it will show you the basics of how it works.

Comment: That sanitizer strips non-whitelisted tags from the input.  That can't be the case with this question title, which has been HTML-encoded to preserve the original output.